# Override pseudo property (after/before) with jQuery with dynamic style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to override the style of after/before with jQuery? I have dynamic values, calculated from JS, so I can't add a class.

I need something like, how we override classes with adding jQuery inline styles but for :after and :before pseudo class.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Check out this one :["Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-using-jquery/21709814#21709814)

Comment: Short answer, you can't.